# Can text be added to existing ListViewSubItems

Tags: c++, winforms, listviewitem

I am trying to populate the subItems of a `listView` after the items have already been added to the view itself. This has been throwing an error, and I do not know if it's because I am doing it wrong or if adding to a subitem after it has been created isn't possible.

I have created a windows form with a `listView` on it very imaginatively named `listView1`, which is populated with components and the possible hash functions that can be performed on them. 
[image: listView1]

This works fine and is populated as I would like it to. Now the user clicks a button that is supposed to run those hash functions on each component and populate the appropriate box to the right of each as it is done.

I cannot seem to get each box to fill out. My code:

```
 //Put the verification in the appropriate column, and line
 //Iterate through each row until the appropriate one is found
 for(int j=0;j<this->listView1->Items->Count;j++){
   //When the row matches the component that was just verified, add things to that row
   if(this->listView1->Items[j]->Text == response->componentID){
      //Now that the row has been successfully found, find the column
      for(int k=1;k<this->listView1->Columns->Count;k++){
        //When the column matches the algorithm that was just ran, add the result
        if(this->listView1->Columns[k]->Text == response->algorithmType.ToString()){
           //****The line giving me trouble
           this->listView1->Items[j]->SubItems[k]->Text = response->verifyResult;
           //****End of troublesome line
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Running it as is results in the following popup
[image: listView1ErrorMessage]

Do I just need to create all of the items again and then clear out the `listView1` before adding the "new" items to it? Or is this code salvagable?

Comment: Why does k start at 1?   Why is k used for column index and subitem index?

Comment: k starts at 1 because the 0'th column is the componentID and I don't need to look at that. I'm using K for both because (my understanding of the columns) is that the subitems match up with the columns.

Comment: @WayneO You should first add sub items. `SubItems` collection is empty by default. You added some sub items using `Item.SubItems.Add("some text")`. Then you can change text of sub-item using its index when you need.

Comment: @DarrelLee the 0th subitem is the item text. So when you want to set text of sub items, you use 1-based index.

Comment: @RezaAghaei so if I created empty ones to begin with `Item.SubItems.Add("")` then I could use the indexes to change them later?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you are creating items at first and you don't have any values for sub-items, you can create empty sub items and then if you never remove them from collection, you can be sure there are subitems in collection and simply access them by index.

Comment: @RezaAghaei that solved my problem. If you would like to put it in an answer i'd be happy to put the check by it

Comment: I'll post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ListView.SubItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems(v=vs.110).aspx) collection is empty by default. You should first add sub items using for example [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7x34tef(v=vs.110).aspx) method of sub-items collection. Then after you added some sub items then you can change text of sub-item using its index when you need.

```
this->listView1->Items[i]->SubItems->Add("Some text for SubItem");
```

Also when working on subitems in the collection, use 1-based index for sub-items because index 0 is the item which owns the collection.

```
this->listView1->Items[i]->SubItems[1]->Text = "Some new text";
```